# Java icetea plugin not working

Tags: 11.10, java, icedtea

I installed Java IcedTea plugin 6 on Ubuntu 11.10. It doesnt work in Chrome, and it continues to crash in Firefox , 100% of the time. I tried re-installing and updating but nothing seems to work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all the following packages installed:

```
icedtea-6-jre-cacao                            
icedtea-6-jre-jamvm                             
icedtea-netx                                    
icedtea-netx-common                             
java-common                                     
default-jre                                     
default-jre-headless                            
gcj-4.6-jre-lib                                 
openjdk-6-jre                                   
openjdk-6-jre-headless                          
openjdk-6-jre-lib
```